# What happens when you select multiple plants at once in the Forestation Plant?

Tags: surviving-mars

In Surviving Mars, the Forestation Plant (from the Green Planet DLC) lets you choose multiple plants at once to cultivate, but it's not clear how it operates. Does it:

1. Cultivate them in a sequence (like the farm), for example, if I set it to lichen and grass, does it spend 6 hours on lichen, then 12 hours on grass, then back to the lichen?
2. Cultivate them concurrently, consuming the combined total number of seeds?
3. Something else?